# Ubuntu 20.04 - Ethernet UNCLAIMED, can't upgrade kernel

Tags: networking, ethernet, ubuntu-20.04

Firstly, I've been googling this for hours, and I've seen several questions here, on AskUbuntu, and various other forums where the answer always boils down to "update the kernel". Let me start by saying this is not an option. The issue began immediately after I had to downgrade the kernel because the one it was using was incompatible with security software required by my company (yes, I know, security software incompatible with a higher kernel version is a bit of an oxymoron, but my hands are tied). Here's a breakdown of the situation:

- The server is part of a Cisco UCS domain. I reimaged 6 servers in the same cluster using an Ubuntu 20.04 live server ISO. One of the 6 has worked fine without issues. Somehow, despite using the exact same ISO, 5 of them ended up on a different kernel. These 5 I had to downgrade because of the security software.
- All 6 are using the exact same ethernet controller:

```
root@server:~# lspci | grep -i eth
07:00.0 Ethernet controller: Cisco Systems Inc VIC Ethernet NIC (rev a2)
08:00.0 Ethernet controller: Cisco Systems Inc VIC Ethernet NIC (rev a2)
```

- All 6 are now on the same kernel (note that since one of them is working fine, this rules out compatibility issues with the ethernet controller and the kernel):

```
root@server:~# uname -r
5.4.0-150-generic
```

Also worth noting: the 5 I downgraded were previously on kernel version 5.4.0-152-generic, so it was a small downgrade.

**lshw -C network** (apologies for the screenshot, my only access to this server is via KVM and I don't have clipboard capability there)

[Screenshot of lshw output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tkudi.png)

`ip a` simply shows the loopback interface, no ethernets.

**Netplan configuration**

```
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    enp7s0:
      dhcp4: true
    enp8s0:
      dhcp4: true
  version: 2
```

Since these servers all have the exact same hardware, exact same netplan config, exact same OS and kernel versions, yet only one is working, I am stumped as to why this is happening and could really use some help. Cisco support has been worse than useless. Happy to provide any other command outputs that would make it easier to diagnose. Thanks in advance, everyone!

Comment: Did you downgrade the modules as well? Plenty of such problems show up when the kernel in /boot doesn't match /lib/modules. Which module is used for these NICs on other servers; does it show up as loaded on the problematic one? What's the PCI vendor:product ID from `lspci -nn`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My accounts got messed up when I registered as part of asking this question, but I finally found the solution that I needed after sifting through dozens of other posts throughout stack exchange.

I was just missing the 'linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-150-generic' package.

So if anyone stumbles on this who is as inexperienced as me with messing with the kernel, and having a similar issue, even if 'linux-modules-x.x.x-x-generic' is saying it's installed and up-to-date, the -extra package is a separate thing you also need.

Comment: You are allowed to tick your own answer.

Comment: Soon you are going to run into more trouble installing dependent kernel packages explicitly like that. They are supposed to be pulled in by the [Kernel Metapackages](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MetaPackages). Put the packages on [hold](https://askubuntu.com/a/18656) or build your own metapackage that depends on your outdated kernel versions.